# Puppet Could not find declared class

Tags: puppet

I'm seeing the following error on puppet agent run:

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Could not find declared class ::nagios::server at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/site/role/manifests/nagios.pp:2:2 on node mynode.something.co.uk

i have a nagios module which has a server manifest

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with metadata.json file, when I ran:

```
puppet config print modulepath --section master --environment production
```

I got the message:

> Error: No dependencies module metadata provided for nagios

So I added empty array to metadata.json:

```
"dependencies": []
```